# Hide ImageView when it is visible

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview, hide

I have button to display scrollView. I have three images under awesomeView. Then i added awesomeView to scrollView for scrolling. When i click any image the awesomeView will be add to myImageView8. Because the myImageView8 display the awesomeview images to center of the screen. I need to hide myImageView8 or awesomeView when it is visible in the screen

code:

```
scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 420, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    //  CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    // awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    awesomeView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];

    img = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];

    [img setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100,130)];

    [img addTarget:self action:@selector(img:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [img setTag:0];

    [awesomeView addSubview:img];

    img1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [img1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sofa_s2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];
    [img1 setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 0, 100,130)];
    [img1 setTag:1];

    [img1 addTarget:self action:@selector(img1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [awesomeView addSubview:img1];

    img2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [img2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sofa_s3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];

    [img2 setFrame:CGRectMake(210, 0, 100,130)];
    [img2 setTag:2];
    [img2 addTarget:self action:@selector(img2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [awesomeView addSubview:img2];
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

myImageView8 for display awesome to center of the screen:

```
myImageView8=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView8];
myImageView8.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

-(void)img:(id)sender {
    if(myImageView8){
        [myImageView8 removeFromsuperView];
    } 
    else {
        [myImageView8 addSubView:awesomeView];
    }
}

-(void)img1:(id)sender {
    if(myImageView8) {
        [myImageView8 removeFromsuperView];
    }
    else {
        [myImageView8 addSubView:awesomeView];
    }
}

-(void)img2:(id)sender {
    if(myImageView8) {
        [myImageView8 removeFromsuperView];
    }
    else {
    [myImageView8 addSubView:awesomeView];
    }
}
```

If I click button the scroll is displaying. But when I click image, if myImageView8 is visible it reappearing.

[image]

Comment: Your if(myImageView8){
 [myImageView8 removeFromsuperView];
}else{

[myImageView8 addSubView:awesomeView];
}
 condition is wrong if myImageView8 == nil, then how you can add awesomeView subview on it?What is your requirement?

Comment: My need is, if myImageView8 is visible in the screen, when i click image it don't reappear. But, I drag to some position. Then i click one of the image the myImageView8 is reappearing this frame size (0, 50, 320, self.view.frame.size.height). If myImageView8 is i need to hide reappear.

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you want but if you want to change the image of myImageView8, when you click on any of the image in scrollview(ie button), then in button click do not remove myImageView8, just change the image of myImageView8, by myImageView8.image = @"imagenameyouwanttodisplay".

Comment: @NuzhatZari: See the above picture. When i click one button kids,women,men images are display. After click one of the image the myImageView8 will display to center of the screen. After drag,pinch,zoom. When i click the one of the image the myImageView8 again displaying all the images. If images displaying in the screen, i need to hide the reappear